# Limit question involving prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can anyone help me show that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n}{(\ln(n))^2} + \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\ln(n)} - \sum_{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}}\frac{\frac{n}{p^2}}{(\ln(\frac{n}{p^2}))^2}}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)} = 0$$

where $p \leq \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ means all prime numbers less than or equal to $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$

If I am wrong that the limit equals $0$, can someone else give me another answer. It is fine if this equals a constant $c$, I just need to show that this is not infinity.

Comment: My bad... it was supposed to be a minus sign before the sigma function... I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at only the first term,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{(\ln{(n)})^2}}{\sqrt{n}\ln{(n)}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln(n))^3}$

Since

$n^{\epsilon}=e^{\epsilon\ln(n)}=1+\epsilon\ln(n)+\dots\geq \epsilon\ln(n)$
$\Rightarrow \ln(n)\leq \frac{n^{\epsilon}}{\epsilon}, \forall\epsilon>0$.

Thus we have

$\ln(n)^3\leq \left(\frac{n^{1/9}}{1/9}\right)^3=9^3n^{1/3}$
$\Rightarrow\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln(n))^3}\geq \frac{1}{9^3}{n^{1/6}}$
$\Rightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\ln(n))^3}\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{9^3}{n^{1/6}}=\infty$

The other terms in your numerator are clearly positive. Hence, the limit in question is $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... except that I made a mistake and edited the question so that there is a negative sign before the sigma sign.. so the other terms are not all positive haha